# Deseo mostrar una tabla llamada juegos de mi base de datos en una tabla responsiva boostrap mas sin embargo no se muestra nada

Tags: php, javascript, html5

**archivo Database.php**

```
class Database
 {
     private $PDOLocal;
     private $user = "root";
     private $password = "";
     private $server = "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=smashinc;charset=utf8";

     public function conectarDB()
     {
         try
         {
             $this->PDOLocal = new PDO($this->server,$this->user,$this->password); 
         }
         catch(PDOException $e)
         {
             echo "Error de Conexion";
             echo $e->getMessage();
         }
     }         
         public function ejecutarSQL($query)
         {
            try{
                $this->PDOLocal->query($query);
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
               echo $e->getMessage(); 
            }
         }
         public function desconectarDB()
         {
             try
             {
                 $this->PDOLocal = null;
             }
              catch(PDOException $e)
            {
               echo $e->getMessage(); 
            }
         }
         public function seleccionar($query)
         {
             try
             {
                $resultado = $this->PDOLocal->query($query);
                $renglon = $resultado->rowCount();

                 if($renglon > 0)
                 {
                     while($row = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                     {
                         $Datos[]=$row;
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     $Datos[] = null;
                 }

                 return $Datos;

             }
              catch(PDOException $e)
            {
               echo $e->getMessage(); 
            }
         }     
 }
```

**archivo Juegos.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    require_once 'Database.php';
    header('Content-type:application/json');
    extract($_POST);

    try
    {
        $db = new Database();
        $db->conectarDB();
        $accion = "seleccionar";

        switch($accion)
        {
            case "seleccionar":
                $Juego["juegos"] = $db->seleccionar("SELECT Nombre,Genero,Descripcion,Lanzamiento,UnidadesD,Version,Plataforma,Precio,Region from juegos"); 
                break;
        }

        echo ($Juego !== null)? json_encode($Juego) : "{}";

        $db->desconectarDB();        
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

**app js que insertara datos en la tabla**

```
var ajaxJuegos = function(accion,url,formulario){

    var datos = $('#'+formulario).serializeArray();
    datos.push({name:'accion',value:accion});

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:datos,
        type:"POST",
        datatype:"JSON",
        success:function(response){

            if(response.juegos !== null){
                $.each(response.juegos, function(index,juego){
                    $('#tablaJuegos tbody').append(
                        "<tr><td>"+juego.Nombre+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.Genero+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.Descripcion+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.Lanzamiento+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.UnidadesD+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.Version+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.Plataforma+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.Precio+"</td>"+"<td>"+juego.Region+"</td>"+"</tr>"
                        );
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**llamar en el index a app.js**

```
<script src="boostrap/dist/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            ajaxJuegos('seleccionar','scripts/Juegos.php','IJuegos');
        });
    </script>
```

**El formulario**

```
<div class="container">
<form id="IJuegos" method="post">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="Panel-Title">Nuestros Juegos</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="Panel-body">
            <table id="tablaJuegos" class="table table-bordered tabe-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>                        
                        <th>Genero</th>
                        <th>Descripcion</th>
                        <th>Lanzamiento</th>
                        <th>UnidadesD</th>
                        <th>Version</th>
                        <th>Plataforma</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Region</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```